# How to save logs from httpclient right?

Tags: yii2

I use yii2-httpclient for saving my http-logs. I set target to catch this kind of logs into a file I need. I call in place where logs starts to write the next string

```
\Yii::$app->log->targets['my_logs']->logFile = \Yii::$app->getRuntimePath() . '/here is the way to file/file.log';
```

But the problem is that for the first call the file doesn't exist and I forced to create directory and file using mkdir and fopen. Could I bypass this forced creation?

Answer (score 0):

Log folder is being created if it's not there (see [this line of code](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.12/framework/log/FileTarget.php#L90)).

If like in your case Yii can not create this directory it means PHP has got no permission to do it and you need to sort this out first. For Linux use proper `chmod`, `chown` commands.